# Blue Screen of Death - My Sony laptop crashes very often

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, hardware-failure, bsod, sony-vaio

I have a Sony VAIO laptop which is giving me blue screen problem from some days. I thought it might be because of corrupted Operating system, so I refereshed the operating system installation but the problem persists.

Following are the details about my system's hardware and software.

```
 Manufacturer: Sony
 Model: PCG-71311L Sony VAIO
 Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 430 @ 2.27GHz(4CPUs), ~2.3GHz
 Memory: 4096MB RAM
 BIO: BIOS Date: 09/23/09 11:58:43 Version: 08.00.10
 System Model: VPCEB2AFD
 Display Name: Intel (R) HD Graphics
 Chip Type: Intel(R) HD Graphics (Core i5)
 Approx. Total Memory: 1751MB
 HDD : 300 GB Western Digital

 Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate - SP1, 64bit
 Direct X 11.
```

I also note something, that when the computer isn't connected to the internet, it often doesn't cause problem, the blue screen comes only when its connected to the internet. Now it may be by chance, or it may be the reason.

The Problem details it shows after recovering from the blue screen are as follows

```
    Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   124
  BCP1: 0000000000000000
  BCP2: FFFFFA80069E1028
  BCP3: 00000000BE000000
  BCP4: 0000000000800400
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\010415-14866-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Moon computer\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-28376-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank You all in advance.

Comment: I suggest you install two softwares an Antivirus and a System Optimizer app my preference is System Mechanic other alternatives are fine too. Work with this two and first scan your computer for viruses and then do a clean up of pc, registery, ram. If the problem persists after these all tell us. Last choice is reinstalling windows

Comment: Check for warning/error entries in the (system) logs. Right click `My computer`, select `Manage` and find it in there.

Comment: A registry cleaner? no better way to make your pc unusable.

Comment: [Try Bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), it may give a clue to what is responsible for the crash

Comment: upload this file to get more help: **C:\Windows\Minidump\010415-14866-01.dmp**

Comment: Dear Hannu how to check warning/error after selecting Manage....?????

Comment: Techlife the stil presists....

Comment: as I already told you upload the dmp files from **C:\Windows\Minidump** to a cloud service, post the link here, otherwise we **CAN'T** help you.

Comment: okz ... but where i have to upload the file please

Comment: to a file hosting service like dropbox, OneDrive, zippyshare.com or https://www.wetransfer.com/. There are so many of them.

Comment: while uploading the file this msg appears " you are unable to open this file..."

Comment: copy the minidump folder to your desktop, create a zip of the minidump folder and upload this zip.

Comment: the link is here please.....https://www.dropbox.com/home

Answer (score -1):

Blue screen occurs when there is a file corruption(bad sector or software bug) or **Hardware** problem happens to **prevent data loss** or **hardware damage**.

In this case that you mentioned, Hardware issue is mostly probable.

check these conditions:

- when it shows blue screen, is the bottom of your LP **hot or too warm**?
- is your **CPU Fan** working properly?
- is there a **short circuit** in your Ethernet Cable or inside its socket?

  (if not using Wi-Fi)
- have you ever tried running windows on `Safe Mode` or `Safe Mode with
  Networking` (By Pressing<kbd>F8</kbd> before windows startup) and
  testing the functionality?
- Does your problem occurs when using your LP **heavily** or sth?

Comment: dear FRIENDS after uninstalling some software i.e, IDM and Vedio palyer , now the problem doesn't appear yet.

Comment: :) I'm glad so!

Comment: but dear i need to run these software so what should be the alternative....????

Comment: Actually i don't think IDM Could cause a problem, cause i have installed it on my system and its working just fine (However you can update it if it's old ver. or use a previous stable one). I think the most probable case is your video player cause it wanna use your GPU, and there might be an issue with your GPU driver or your player. my suggestion is to update your GPU driver or use a better stable Video Player (i.e [KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/) which is free). hope it'll help you!

Comment: Dear problem i am again facing blue screen problem..

Comment: the fan is working properly.. no short circuit problem..... LP not too warm.... i think there some hardware problem... help me that hardware problem would identified.

Comment: sorry dear frnd

Comment: What about the 4th and 5th? did u tried using `Safe Mode`? or trying to use heavily? i think using network in safe mode would help u to find the problem. give me the results :)

Comment: Dear bro tried 4th and 5th not facing the problem in safe mode....

Comment: So it's definitely a software issue. most probable with the Video Player. my suggestion is to try functionality after installing IDM and Ur Video Player separately and find out the bad working software to act :)

Comment: dear friend after 2days i face problem of blue screen while using in safe mode .... :-(

Comment: What about the softwares? Have you tried installing them separately and testing the functionality? What else have u tried?

Comment: Let me try this....will update about.....